# Group of order $pq, p \leq q, p \not\mid q - 1$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

This is an example from D&F before Cauchy's theorem and before the Sylow theorems.

They first note that $Z(G) = \{e\}$, as otherwise $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic and therefore abelian. Sure.

They then say that if every nonidentity element has order $p$, then the centralizer of every nonidentity element has index $q$, i.e. order $p$. But I'm having a blind spot and I'm not able to see why the centralizer of such an element can't have order $q$.

Comment: Because it contains itself.

Comment: @the_fox Maybe if the centralizer had order $q$ then this would mean that there's a cyclic subgroup of order $q$, and hence an element of order $q$?

Comment: If $C$ is a cyclic subgroup of the group $G$, then $C_G(C) \geq C$. Thus the centralizer of an element of order $p$ in a group of order $pq$ can't possibly have order $q$.

Comment: @the_fox I agree that the centralizer of an element of order $p$ must have order $\geq p$. But why not $q$?

Comment: Because $p$ must **divide** the order of the centralizer by Lagrange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be an element of order $p$. (Thus, $x \neq e$.)
The centraliser $C_G(x)$ is the subgroup $C_G(\langle x\rangle)$ (by definition).

Now, note that $\langle x\rangle$ is abelian and hence, $\langle x\rangle \le C_G(x).$
This gives us that $p \mid |C_G(x)|$. (Lagrange's theorem)

Thus, $|C_G(x)| = p$ or $|C_G(x)| = pq$.
However, if the order were $pq$, then we would have $C_G(x) = G$. This would imply that every element of $G$ commutes with $x$.
In turn, this would give us that $x \in Z(G)$. This contradicts the fact that $Z(G) = \{e\} \not\ni x$.

This leaves with the sole possibility that $|C_G(x)| = p$.